# How to archive cron job in node js express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I would like to fetch some data from a API , where data updated vary frequently . i want to hit api on every second to check update. how can i archive this in node js/express, so i can get updated data and store in DB.

Comment: You can just let your Node instance run in background with a `setInterval`.

Comment: Either use `setInterval` in your Node.js application as Seblor sated, or use a cronjob (Linux) or a Scheduled Task (Windows) to run the application over and over again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Cron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron) module which is very easy to implement cron jobs in node/express.